# How to edit text file data with c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a program that create a text file of stock items, which contains detail of 'total production' , 'stock remaining' and so on. Now my question is how do I edit that text file with my program. For example if I mistake to enter a correct data (like production was 500 pieces but enter only 400) now how can I edit my file to make it correct without effecting other data.

Comment: A better example is to replace `500` by `75` (which is one char shorter)

Comment: How big is the text file: megabytes, gigabytes, terabytes?

Comment: why does file size matter???? i can add as many items(data) as I want on the file, so the file size will not be same all the time..

Comment: Because if the file fits entirely (and painlessly) in memory, you don't need to overwrite or edit it. You keep the content in memory, and you dump the new content just before exiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should not create  a text file in the first place. Did you consider using [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) (or indexed files à la [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdbm) ...) or some real database like [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) or [MongoDb](http://mongodb.org/)?

If you insist on editing programmatically a textual file, the only way is to process every line : either keep all of them in memory, or copy them (except the one you'll change) to some new file.... But there is no portable way to change the content of a file in the middle.

You might also be interested in textual [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) formats like [JSON](http://json.org/), [YAML](http://yaml.org/) (or maybe even XML).