# Checking line and then changing its data on a txt file

Tags: c, file, line, edit

So, I have this:

**order.txt**

> file.txt;10;21:21
>
> file2.txt;3;20:00
>
> file2.txt;30;22:20
>
> file4.txt;3;10:00

I want the user to give a desired line (1 to 3, depending how many lines exist) and then change its content. For example:

**Line 3**

"**File name:** file.txt"

"**Seconds:** 5"

"**Time HH:MM:** 20:00"

***Output/Changes into order.txt:***

> file.txt;10;21:21
>
> file2.txt;3;20:20
>
> file.txt;5;20:00
>
> file4.txt;3;10:00

***As you may see, the third line changed. Which for it, I have tried the following:***

**Variables**

```
FILE* orderFile;
FILE* contentFile;
char fileName[50];
char timeValue[10];
int seconds;
char orderNameFile[50];
char orderTimeFile[50];
int orderSecondsFile;
int count = 0;
int i = 0;
int line;
int position;
```

**Code**

```
/* This will show the content on it with the number of the line behind */
orderFile = fopen("order.txt","r+");
                
printf("\n");

while(fscanf(orderFile," %49[^;];%d; %49[^\n]",fileName,&seconds,timeValue) == 3)
{
    i++;
    printf("[%d] %s;%d;%s\n",i,fileName,seconds,timeValue);
}

printf("\n");

rewind(orderFile);
/* ******************************************************************* */

/* This will ask which line he wants to change */
do{

    printf("Choose the line you want to change\n");
    printf("[Line] ");
    scanf("%d",&line);
    printf("\n");

    if(line > i)
    {
         printf("That line does not exist\n\n");
    }

}while(line > i || line < 1);
/* ******************************************* */

/* This will ask for the file name, seconds and time in HH:MM */
printf("Insert the name of the file\n");
printf("[Name] ");
getchar();
scanf("%s",&orderNameFile);

printf("Insert the presentation time in seconds\n");
printf("[Time in seconds] ");
scanf("%d",&orderSecondsFile);

printf("Insert the hour it starts\n");
printf("[Time in HH:MM (Hour:Minutes)] ");
getchar();
scanf("%s%",&orderTimeFile);
/* ******************************************* */

/* This is what is supposed to edit the line I want but does not work */
while(fscanf(orderFile," %49[^;];%d; %49[^\n]",fileName,&seconds,timeValue) == 3)
{
    count++;

    if(count == line)
    {
        position = ftell(orderFile);
        fseek(orderFile, position, SEEK_SET);
        fprintf(orderFile,"%s;%d;%s",orderNameFile,orderSecondsFile,orderTimeFile);
        break;
    }
}
*/ ****************************************************************** */

fclose(orderFile);
```

**Output I want using the first example:**

> file.txt;10;21:21
>
> file2.txt;3;20:20
>
> file.txt;5;20:00
>
> file4.txt;3;10:00

**Output it gives me using the first example @EDITED:**

> file.txt;10;21:21
>
> file2.txt;3;20:00
>
> file2.txt;30;22:20file.txt;5;20:00
>
> file4.txt;3;10:00

Any ideas of what it might be?

Comment: This seems to be a problem connected with your variable `linha`. I can't see any definition of it so I can hardly tell where the problem is. But I guess that first problem would be that `fscanf` in the last loop reads the line, moves the cursor in file and you try to rewrite the line, rewriting the data after it. You need to return the cursor back to the start of the line.

Comment: Question very similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27746175/841108). [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27746214/841108) is also relevant here.

Comment: Sorry I though I translated everything for english, linha = line. How do I put the cursor back to the start of the line? I only know how to put in the first line.. Will check your answer basile.

Comment: @Ran You could probably store the position in file using `ftell` before each iteration of while (e.g. before the first run with declaration and then when you're doing the count++). When you get into the `if (count == line)`, you'd use fseek(orderFile, positionFromFtell, SEEK_SET). Also, it would be a good idea to break the while loop in the if body, giving a reader clear signal, that it is only run once.

Comment: May try copying for another file but didn't want to have many txt files. Also we don't know database yet and I only have 2 days to finish this. In the "work" project it asks to save in files aswell. Alegnem, any suggestion on how to move the "cursor" back?

Comment: Already tried yours Alegnem, and it's almost correct, the only problem is it inserts after the line I choose but does not delete what there was.

Comment: I've changed the code to how is it now (the changes is as you said inside the while/if) and what output it gives me now.

Comment: Load the lines in a list and then modify the line you want and save the list back to the file.

Comment: This might answer your question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151713/delete-a-line-from-a-file-in-c-language

Comment: @Ran, that's not correct, let's go through it once more:  
`ftell` - tells you the offset in file where the cursor is; `scanf` - moves the cursor.
What you need is to store the position of cursor before using the scanf, so the ftell must be outside and inside the while loop (reading the position before first scanf and after each scanf). Then you need to call the fseek in the if body, which you did correctly. Actually I was wrong and you need to put the second ftell (inside the while loop) after the if body. Also, as stated by others, trying to replace shorter/longer text will cause errors.

Comment: I'm understanding what you guys mean. I'll try it today later when I'm okay to program again. I think I'll go with the idea of doing a sort of "backup" with only one line edited and then add it to the "order.txt". Thank you very much, I'll post after if I could get the result or not. :)

Comment: You might like to consider using a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generally works better to write to a temp file and then remove the original and rename the temp file to the name of the original

```
FILE *temp = fopen ( "temp", "w");
/* This is what is supposed to edit the line I want but does not work */
while(fscanf(orderFile," %49[^;];%d; %49[^\n]",fileName,&seconds,timeValue) == 3)
{
    count++;

    if(count == line)
    {
        fprintf(temp,"%s;%d;%s\n",orderNameFile,orderSecondsFile,orderTimeFile);
    }
    else 
    {
        fprintf(temp,"%s;%d;%s\n",filename,seconds,timeValue);
    }
}
fclose ( temp);
fclose ( orderFile);
remove ( "order.txt");// comment these two lines out until you are sure temp is correct
rename ( "temp", "order.txt");//that way you do not loose the original file
```

Comment: I should do "temp.txt" right? Also thank you, did not know it was possible to do that (remove and rename)

Comment: @Ran, in fact you should use one of the random filename generation functions like `mkstemp` if you want to use this approach, there is no guarantee that no other file has this same name, so either check that the file exists before `fopen` or use a different directory like your os default temp directory, or use my solution.

Comment: Ehm it says remove("order.txt"); is not a function or pointer. I have the stdio.h include as well. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the lines and then rewrite them into the file, there could be more elegant/efficient solutions, but for a simple case this should be ok, here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* orderFile;
    char fileName[50];
    char timeValue[10];
    int seconds;
    char orderNameFile[50];
    char orderTimeFile[50];
    int orderSecondsFile;
    int count;
    int lineCount;
    int line;
    char lineContent[128];
    char fileLines[128][128];

    /* This will show the content on it with the number of the line behind */
    orderFile = fopen("order.txt", "r+");
    if (orderFile == NULL)
        return -1;
    lineCount = 0;

    while ((fgets(lineContent, sizeof(lineContent), orderFile) != NULL) && (lineCount < 128))
    {
        size_t length;

        length = strlen(lineContent);
        if (lineContent[length - 1] == '\n')
            lineContent[length - 1] = 0;
        if (sscanf(lineContent, " %49[^;];%d; %49[^\n]", fileName, &seconds, timeValue) == 3)
        {
            strcpy(fileLines[lineCount], lineContent);
            printf("[%d] %s;%d;%s\n", ++lineCount, fileName, seconds, timeValue);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    rewind(orderFile);

    /* This will ask which line he wants to change */
    do {

        printf("Choose the line you want to change\n");
        printf("[Line] > ");

        scanf("%d", &line);

        if ((line > lineCount) || (line < 1))
             printf("That line does not exist\n\n");
    } while ((line > lineCount) || (line < 1));

    /* This will ask for the file name, seconds and time in HH:MM */
    printf("Insert the name of the file\n");
    printf("[Name] ");

    scanf("%49s", orderNameFile);

    printf("Insert the presentation time in seconds\n");
    printf("[Time in seconds] ");

    scanf("%d", &orderSecondsFile);

    printf("Insert the hour it starts\n");
    printf("[Time in HH:MM (Hour:Minutes)] ");

    scanf("%49s", orderTimeFile);

    /* This is what is supposed to edit the line I want but does not work */
    count = 0;
    while (++count < lineCount + 1)
    {
        if (count == line)
            fprintf(orderFile, "%s;%d;%s\n", orderNameFile, orderSecondsFile, orderTimeFile);
        else
            fprintf(orderFile, "%s\n", fileLines[count - 1]);
    }
    fclose(orderFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yet that will probably insert it down where I don't want anyways. I want for example change "file1.txt;5;20:00" to "file.txt;4;20:00" in a chosen line. Ex: There are 4 lines, I want to edit line 2 to something different. On my case it doesn't and adds it on the ending of the file.

Comment: @Ran I'll come back to your question later, it's interesting to see what you want to do, If you could add some examples it would be good. Now I have something to do, but I'll come back in an hour or so.

Comment: The example of the at the moment output is now on the ending. I only need to delete what's behind of what I want to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the contents of the file is a costly operation the better way to handle this is

1. Open a new file with write mode
2. Start writing the contents of your previous file to this new file.
3. Once you reach the line which should be replaced make sure you ignore the read line and write the new line to the new file using `fprintf()`

IMO this is much easier and right way to do this. Used the below thread as reference

[Delete a Line from a file in C Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151713/delete-a-line-from-a-file-in-c-language)